# Sort List of Lists of Lists Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a List of Lists of Lists in python. I need to sort the highest level of lists based on one of the values in the lowest levels.

For a toy model, my list is created first with list `small`, which is a list containing lists with three items each:

```
    small = [["dog", 5, 6], ["cat", 391, 130], ["pig", 45, 2]...]`
```

Then there is a larger list, `large`, that is created by appending the small list and another item together:

```
    large.append([["category 1"], small])`
```

This is done in a loop, so if the loop has a counter of 5, it will proceed through a function that creates a list `small` 5 times, each time, appending it to list `large`.

My goal is to sort the final list based on an element in the smallest list (the list that comprises the `small` list). I am currently printing the `large` list out line by line, with the `small` list ordered by the `index 1` of the lists within it (see: 5,10,15 in order, 1,3,6 in order, etc), so my output is this:

```
    >category 1:
    >['Dog', 5, 6]
    >['Pig', 10, 2]
    >['Cat', 15, 130]
    >['Buffalo', 20, 1]
    >['Newt', 25, 45]

    >category 2:
    >['Newt', 1, 1092]
    >['Cat', 3, 352]
    >['Pig', 6, 34]
    >['Buffalo', 9, 12]
    >['Dog', 12, 5]

    >category 3:
    >['Buffalo', 2, 12]
    >['Pig', 4, 37]
    >['Cat', 6, 34]
    >['Newt', 8, 150]
    >['Dog', 10, 52]
```

However, i would like to print the `large` list in order of smallest to largest when looking at the element in `index 1` in the list that makes up the smallest array. So my ideal output would be this:

```
    >category 2:
    >['Newt', 1, 1092]
    >['Cat', 3, 352]
    >['Pig', 6, 34]
    >['Buffalo', 9, 12]
    >['Dog', 12, 5]

    >category 3:
    >['Buffalo', 2, 12]
    >['Pig', 4, 37]
    >['Cat', 6, 34]
    >['Newt', 8, 150]
    >['Dog', 10, 52]

    >category 1:
    >['Dog', 5, 6]
    >['Pig', 10, 2]
    >['Cat', 15, 130]
    >['Buffalo', 20, 1]
    >['Newt', 25, 45]
```

I have tried sorting with `itemgetter()`, however, when sorting `large` with `itemgetter()`, i can only sort the items in list `large`, which are `[category x]` and `[[a,b,c], [a,b,c]]`. Is there a way to access the lowest level of elements for itemgetter? or another way to go about sorting this list?

Thanks.

Comment: Write it out as a normal loop first and then see about making it simpler or more efficient.

Comment: nested indexing?  `large[i][j][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one line:

```
sorted_large = sorted(large, key=lambda item: item[1][0][1])
```

The [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function takes a `key` parameter:

> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element

Using a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression, the sorting key can be extracted.